# How to set baseline sound volume level before video editing & sound mixing

Tags: audio

It is clear from the various sound volume levels of videos out there that the sound volume that the creator perceives may not match most other viewers' volume settings since everyone is listening to sound with different computer hardware and settings.  Some videos are too loud while others are too low.  To complicate matters, there can be a few different volume adjustments: sound driver settings, speaker/headphone volume adjustments, maybe more.

Is there some baseline volume level that I should set my volume at before I start video/sound editing?

Answer (score 1):

This article - [How to Set Audio Levels for Video](http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/how-to-set-audio-levels-for-video/) - offers some good advice. To summarize:

> Overall Mix Level: -10db to -14db
>
> Dialogue: -12db to -15db
>
> Music: -18db to -22db
>
> Sound Effects: -10db to -20db with occasional spikes up to -8db.

I usually set the voice a bit louder (-8 to -10 dB), but take these as a rough guide.